# D3, Vue, and Typescript: how to fix common errors for "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0" and "Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, d3.js

Disclaimer: I am new to Typescript. Feel free to link docs to read up more on. I have reviewed the errors in isolation (outside the context of d3) but those solutions did not fix it.

I have a mixin:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component, Mixin, Mixins } from 'vue-mixin-decorator';
import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

import CoreMixin from './core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Mixin
export default class BandAxis extends Mixins<CoreMixin>(CoreMixin) {
  // relevant props
  @Prop({}) private sizeTo!: string;
  @Prop({default: () => ( ['one', 'two', 'three'] )}) private labels!: string[];
  // lots of other props props


  // relevant code
  get scale() {
    return d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(this.labels)
      .rangeRound([0, this.width])
      .padding(0.1);
  }

  get axis() {
    return d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(this.scale)
      .ticks(this.labels.length);
  }
  private bbox() {
    const sel = d3.select(`#${this.sizeTo}`);
    if (sel.empty()) {
      return {
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
      };
    } else {
      return sel.node().getBoundingClientRect();
    }
  }
  // more stuff that isn't related
}
```

Using this gives me:

```
 Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
  get axis() {
>  return d3.axisBottom()
```

and:

```
Object is possibly 'null'. 
  |       };
  |     } else {
> |       return sel.node().getBoundingClientRect();
  |              ^
  |     }
  |  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first message indicates that the call to `d3.axisBottom` is missing an argument. It [expects an `AxisScale<Domain>` argument](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f0ce987/types/d3-axis/index.d.ts#L326).

The second message is warning you that `sel` can be `null`. It is treated as an error when compiling with [`--strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) (or `--strict`) enabled. To address that, you could either:

- disable `strictNullCheck` (not recommended)
- add a `null`-check for `sel`: `if (sel) { /* use sel */ }`
- use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator): `sel!.node().getBoundingClientRect()`